# How to use Views Photos Grid module with custom minimal theme

Tags: theming, javascript

I use Views Photos Grid module and it shows the results correctly with Stark theme.
However, it shows all the images stacked in only place in my custom theme.
I do include modules css and js files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/views_photo_grid/css/views-photo-grid.css">
<script src="/core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js?v=8.6.3"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.js?v=8.6.3"></script>
<script src="/modules/views_photo_grid/js/views-photo-grid.js"></script>
```

I also render the expected divs:

```
<section class="viewnodes">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-10">
<div class="views-photo-grid-container">

<div class="views-photo-grid-item">
  <a href="/node/30">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/styles/screenshot/public/2019-01/img04.jpg?itok=yxujuA6O" width="300" height="300" alt="asdf" typeof="foaf:Image" />
  </a>
</div>

...more views-photo-grid-item divs are here...

</div><!--views-photo-grid-container-->
</div><!--col-10-->
</div><!--container-->
</section><!--viewnodes-->
```

Java script console shows no errors.
I've checked in debugger that the main JS function `(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings)` is called but none of the other JS functions is called.
Could this be the cause?

Answer (score -1):

Issue was missing JS includes.
The working set is:

```
  <script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">{"path":{"baseUrl":"\/","scriptPath":null,"pathPrefix":"","currentPath":"screenshots","currentPathIsAdmin":false,"isFront":false,"currentLanguage":"en"},"pluralDelimiter":"\u0003","google_analytics":{"trackOutbound":true,"trackMailto":true,"trackDownload":true,"trackDownloadExtensions":"7z|aac|arc|arj|asf|asx|avi|bin|csv|doc(x|m)?|dot(x|m)?|exe|flv|gif|gz|gzip|hqx|jar|jpe?g|js|mp(2|3|4|e?g)|mov(ie)?|msi|msp|pdf|phps|png|ppt(x|m)?|pot(x|m)?|pps(x|m)?|ppam|sld(x|m)?|thmx|qtm?|ra(m|r)?|sea|sit|tar|tgz|torrent|txt|wav|wma|wmv|wpd|xls(x|m|b)?|xlt(x|m)|xlam|xml|z|zip"},"viewsPhotoGrid":{"gridPadding":"1"},"user":{"uid":0,"permissionsHash":"797a0805952a191ed3acd8cc0feee5a8b53895cab4446ce069563dbdd87139da"}}</script>

  <script src="/core/assets/vendor/domready/ready.min.js?v=1.0.8"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=3.2.1"></script>
  <script src="/core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js?v=8.6.3"></script>
  <script src="/core/misc/drupal.js?v=8.6.3"></script>
  <script src="/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=8.6.3"></script>
  <script src="/modules/views_photo_grid/js/views-photo-grid.js"></script>
```

It doesn't work without the first messy line with `data-drupal-selector`. I wish I knew was is this good for...

Comment: Are you manually adding script assets directly in the template? This really is not a good idea. Learn [how to attach assets](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)